How to count a specific word from a string in a cell from the entire column in google sheets
I have a data in a column like the name of Fruits with comma separate, to which I want to find a count of each fruit occurrence in the cells.
Sample data the entire data is in one column.
Fruits
Apple
Apple, Mango, Banana
Mango, Grapes
Mango
Grapes, Apple
Banana, Mango, Apple
Papaya, Mango, Apple, Grapes
Banana, Papaya, Apple
Banana                      


I tried COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Apple") am getting the result as 1, but am expecting the answer as 6 Apple.

To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas, the recommended method is to create a markdown table. Use this tool to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Additionally you can also share a sample sheet showcasing your input with realistic-demo data & expected output(manually entered). You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker to ease the process of sharing

If you just want to count the appearances, you can use COUNTIF with wildcards, like this:
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&C1&"*")



One odd scenario to be vary of using wildcards as such is that Apple would also automatically match(and take into count) Pineapple

Use Split() and Join() Functions
It reconstructs all the fruits on column A as individual Array per element and then the countif function counts all the occurrences of the fruits.
You may try this:
={unique(transpose(split(substitute(join(",",$A$2:$A$10)," ", ""),","))),arrayformula(countif(split(substitute(join(",",$A$2:$A$10)," ", ""),","),unique(transpose(split(substitute(join(",",$A$2:$A$10)," ", ""),",")))))}

Sample Output:

Reference:
Google Sheets Function List

Simpler formula =QUERY(TOCOL(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A10,", ")),1),"select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1",1).

An alternative using QUERY where the formula in cell E1 is;
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("|",,A1:A),",", "|")," ",""),"|")),"Select Col1, Count(Col1) Group By Col1 Label Count(Col1) ''")

.


May be simpler version =QUERY(TOCOL(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A10,", ")),1),"select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1",1).

@Harun24hr nice formula.
